# Adding a class to para onclicking a button in angular 5

Tags: css, angular5

I want to add class to my paragraph once I click the edit font icon. Can anyone help me with this? Thank you.

```
<style>
 .cust-style{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ef4048;
    display: inline-block;
    outline: none;
}
</style>
<p class="cust-style">Need to add a class for thisd paragraph</p>
<i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this code will help you! Thanks

```
<p [attr.contenteditable]="isClicked" [ngClass]="{ 'className': isClicked }">Hello World!</p>
<button (click)="isClicked = !isClicked">Add Class</button>
```

Comment: Works well, thanks a lot, Hassan. Can u tell me how I can add contenteditable attr for the para if I click the same edit icon

Comment: I just update the above code. Now you can toggle contenteditable attr by clicking the button.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <p [ngClass]="isClicked ? 'addClassHere' : ' '"></p>

  <i (click)=addClass()></i>

in component.ts 
  isClicked: boolean = false
   toggleClass(){
    this.isClicked = !this.isClicked
    // or this.isClicked = true; // for adding class once
  }
```

class will be add and remove on clicking